# how to group list according to an axis

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following list:

```html
c_list= [[1,2,1],[4,6,8],[3,4,1],[3,2,8]
```

I want to group the elements of the list that have the equal (last element).
Here for example, I want to obtain the result:
c_list= [[[1,2,1],[3,4,1]],[4,6,8],[3,2,8]]
In this result as you see I have two arrays, one with the element that have 1 at the end, and one with the elements that has 8 at the end.
Is there a way to group them this way with python?

Answer (score 0):

Apply `itertools.groupby` in the following way:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

c_list = [[1,2,1], [4,6,8], [3,4,1]]
gen_groups = (list(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(c_list, key=itemgetter(2)), key=itemgetter(2)))
res = [g if len(g) > 1 else g[0] for g in gen_groups]
print(res)
```

---

```
[[[1, 2, 1], [3, 4, 1]], [4, 6, 8]]
```